# How to send mail to multiple recipients in Perl?

Tags: perl, email

I have to send mail to multiple recipients using Perl. I have to use [`Net::SMTP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP) only to send mail.

I have to read from and to mail address from pipe separated file. Format of file is as follows:

```
abc@gmail.com|pqr@yahoo.com,xyz@gmail.com
```

I have read the line and split it wrt to pipe. Then I stored to part in `$mailT`

I tried using

```
smtp->recipient($mailT)
```

and

```
smtp->datasend("To: $mailT ");
```

but this is not working.

It gives the error:

```
Issue RCTP to in the command
```

Comment: Should the comma before `xyz` be replaced by a pipe?

Comment: No, It is to part and hence there should be comma

Comment: I recommend to actually study the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP) of the module. It is well documented on how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Net::SMTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP#recipient-ADDRESS-ADDRESS-...-OPTIONS):

> `recipient ( ADDRESS [, ADDRESS, [...]] [, OPTIONS ] )`
>
> Notify the server that the current message should be sent to all of the addresses given. Each address is sent as a separate command to the server. Should the sending of any address result in a failure then the process is aborted and a false value is returned. It is up to the user to call reset if they so desire.

I couldn't identify how your code set `$mailT` but
the argument of `recipient` must be in an array or a list.
That could be an issue if that's a comma separated scalar.